# How does using a vial of acid as a weapon work?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

An adventure pours a vial of acid on an enemy combatant. I assume the enemy will try to avoid this.

How can this be handled with the rules of the game?
How does this change if the acid vial is thrown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is written in the Player's Handbook on page 148:

> ***Acid.*** As an action, you can splash the contents of the vial onto a creature within 5 feet of you or throw the vial up to 20 feet, shattering it on impact. In either case, make a ranged attack against a creature or object, treating the acid as an improvised weapon. On a hit, the target takes 2d6 acid damage.

Remember that a ranged attack in melee range gives you disadvantage, so that covers the part where the enemy is trying to avoid the attack.

Comment: I wouldn't have said it's the "disadvantage while within 5'" rule that models the enemy trying to avoid it, it's the fact that the enemy has an AC.

Comment: I agree with nitsua and to elaborate, the explanation for the "disadvantage while within 5 feet" rule is that it's much harder to aim a ranged weapon because the person within 5 feet of you is actively trying to impede your aim. In the context of a vial of acid, this could be them trying to grab your arm to stop you from throwing it. For a bow it could be them pushing the bow aside.